# How to give classes in CSS modules better names?

Tags: css, webpack, css-modules

I have this config in `webpack.config.js`:

```
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
      {loader: "style-loader"},
      {
        loader: "css-loader",
        options: {
          modules: true,
          importLoaders: 1,
          sourceMap: true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

It works as expected, but the one small thing can be improved - names of classes generated.

Is it possible to, say, add the generated string to the existing class name?

Like this:

```
// before:
   gSJW8QAdF0l_JiFWFeyjq

// after:
   loginContainer_gSJW8QAdF0l_JiFWFeyjq
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to the [official docs](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#scope) and look for the section about **localIdentName** and **getLocalIdent**. Using that you can completely customize your class name. Cheers!